# Which tag would I use for questions about the FAQ itself?

Tags: support, tags, meta

If were to ask a question *about* the FAQ, which tag could I use? The [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag is not meant for this purpose and is a moderator-only tag, so that rules it out.

I've searched the tags for Meta (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags), and couldn't find one that matched the search term `faq`, except for [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) and [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed).

Which tag should I use for questions *about* the FAQ?

Comment: `discussion` and/or `support` would make sense, I don't think anything else is needed (at least not without a more specific example)

Comment: There isn't a specific tag for questions about the [meta-tag:faq]. Just post your question using one of the mandatory tags, if your question is interesting the community will help to tag it appropiately.

Comment: Are you going to ask a question about something that is written in a specific faq or about the functionality of the faq?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [support](/questions/tagged/support) tag to cover questions about the FAQ.  You're looking to clarify a question about the site's features, not necessarily to have a discussion *about* the site.